# mysql event schedule every sunday

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm trying to create event schedule on Mysql and set it to work every sunday 00:00

```
CREATE
    EVENT `reset_column`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS '2013-03-17 03:00:00'
    DO BEGIN

    END */$$
DELIMITER ;
```

this works but I just want to find another way to tell it to do it exactly at the beginning of every week (e.g ON SCHEDULE EVERY SUNDAY )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 WEEK
  STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY
```

This works by getting the day the DDL is run([CURRENT_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date)), then adding the days till the next Sunday to that date. It determines the next Sunday by finding that date's [WEEKDAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) index(0-6), then subtracting it from Sunday's [WEEKDAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) index(6). Once you set the start date to the next Sunday, you repeat every 1 week.

For the date `2023-04-29`, which is a Saturday.

```
2023-04-29 + INTERVAL (6 - 5) Day = 2023-04-30
```

Comment: May you please tell me what's the meaning of `EVERY 2 WEEK`? Is that mean twice within the week or each 2 weeks once?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: That would mean ONCE EVERY 2 WEEKS (ie 14 DAYS).